# Список Анимаций Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется список Анимаций:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При использовании данного кода прокручивается только первая в списке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу сослаться к "MenuHide" (он же Element1)?

При использовании данной записи выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже придется делать цикл:

```
public void PlayAnimation(string animationName) {    
     foreach(AnimationState state in First) {
        if (state.name == animationName) {
            First.Play(state.name);      
            break;
        }
     }
 }

 PlayAnimation("MenuHide");
```

Я бы рекомендовал занести список анимаций в словарь (Например один раз в `OnStart()`). Где ключ - имя анимации, значение - сама анимация. Тогда включить анимацию будет просто:

```
animationDictionary["MenuHide"].Play();
```

Чтобы каждый раз не проигрывать цикл.

Comment: Доброго времени суток. Если использовать данный код, то выдает предупреждение: https://imgur.com/a/yAwwtBV

Comment: @Eniwent надо свою анимацию пометить как legacy если ты используешь Animation вместо Animator: https://forum.unity.com/threads/animationclip-must-be-marked-as-legacy.213952/#post-1494616 
 --- https://answers.unity.com/questions/577801/animation-must-be-marked-as-legacy.html

Answer (score 0):

Добавляешь компонент Animator к объекту, открываешь Аниматор (он на Windows-Amination-Animator), на Аниматоре нажимаешь на Parametres, кликаешь по "+", выбираешь Int и называешь как хочешь(ниже я назвал MyAnim). От AnyStates(или как тебе надо) проводишь стрелки к анимациям. Кликаешь по стрелкам и для каждой в Conditions  ставишь от 0 до определенного числа, сколько есть стрелок. Обязательно поменяй на Equals в Conditions, и желательно убрать Has Exit Time.

```
Animator anim;
public GameObject MyObj; //объект с анимациями

void Start()
    {
        anim = myObj.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

if (Условие1)
            {
                anim.SetInteger("MyAnim", 0); //там где ставил 0, та анимация будет проигрываться
            }
else if(Условие2)
            {
                anim.SetInteger("MyAnim", 1); //и т.д.
            }
else if(Условие3)
            {
                anim.SetInteger("MyAnim", 2);
            }
```

Конечно не идеально, лучше уроки посмотри, я примерно написал.